# How do I disable the diff dialog in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Does anyone know how I can turn off this annoying Diff popup that appears when I accidentally click the gutter?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Is this really Visual Studio? I know it from Visual Studio Code only.

Comment: Yes, it really is Visual Studio. Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.5.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is Line-staging support, also known as interactive staging, to manage it after it was released you can go to `Tools` > `Options` > `Text Editor` > `Advanced` and set `Click to peek in margin` to `Off`:

[image]

You also can set it to double-click to prevent accidental ones but still to have an ability to still use the feature.

See also:

- [Stage lines of code in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/version-control/git-line-staging?view=vs-2022) doc (especially tips in [Peek Difference support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/version-control/git-line-staging?view=vs-2022#peek-difference-support) section)

Comment: Oh my gosh, thank you so much!  Will award bounty when it lets me.

Comment: Can confirm this is where the option is on VS 17.6.5. Thanks @GuruStron!

Comment: Yep that's it - thanks. Annoying that they changed it's name after the preview.

Comment: FYI, looks like you have to restart VS after turning the setting off for it to completely stop showing the ticks in the margin.

Answer (score 1):

Update：

[image: 3]

After my reproduction, after I created a local git repository in VS2022 17.5.1, the click will appear.

Disable the third option to close it.

[image: 4]

---

Are you using any plugins? I haven't seen this window in Visual Studio.

Can't you click the X in the upper right corner of the picture to close it?

[image]

You probably want to remove this feature, I think you can remove it in the extension.

[image]

Comment: It's not a plugin. It is a part of Visual Studio that just appeared after a recent update. Yes the X closes it, but I am trying to disable it completely.

Comment: I updated my VS to the latest version and did not find this feature. I am using the community version. Can you tell me the steps to reproduce? From my search, I found two clues: I am inclined that you used [vs diff](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/comparing-files-in-visual-studio/), and possibly [live share](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-live-share-for-real-time-code-reviews-and-interactive-education/). Are you using git?

Comment: To repro, all you do is click the highlighted area in the left gutter which shows up when you make a change (you can see this in the screen dump above). Yes I am using git. I just checked and I don't have vs diff, although I do somehow have live share (although I have never used it)

Comment: Ugh yes that's it. Well done! Great job finding that option...!

Comment: I'm on VS 2022 17.6.2 and I don't have the same set of options under "Preview Features". Any idea where they moved it now?

Comment: 500 pt bounty started to help find the "new" place for this setting.  I hope to heck it still exists.